# How to sanitize an array to be properly converted to json string

Tags: php, json

How do i properly convert an array into a json string?
I'm fetching data from amazon, ebay, flickr and freebase and some of the data that is returned isn't safe to be converted to json.

Here's the json string that I'm currently getting after using `json_encode()`

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/126688107/invalid_json.txt

I've already tried using `addslashes()` to escape double quotes. But I'm also getting strings with single quotes so I'm also using `str_replace("'", "\'", $string_with_single_quotes)`

But I'm also getting things like:

```
"parent":null
"nodes":[]
```

Which I don't know if its a valid json.
I'm also getting `addslashes()` that has gone overboard:

```
It is the world\\\\\\'s
```

What I need is a tool that can point me what makes the json string that I have invalid.
I tried this http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsonschemaphpv/ but it doesn't seem to recognize json that has multiple items. It always says its invalid because the string that I have is wrapped in `[]`

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**update**

For those who are asking why do I think this is invalid json.
I'm actually saving the json string to the database and when I retrieve it and use `json_decode($str, true)` to convert it to an array it simply returns `NULL`

Comment: Output from `json_encode` should *always* be perfectly valid JSON, no matter what the input. What exactly are you doing to produce the output you're producing?

Comment: Why do you think the output is invalid JSON?

Comment: That JSON seems perfectly valid to me!

Comment: @above according to [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/) it is not

Comment: I'm actually saving the json string to the database and when I retrieve it and use `json_decode($str, true)` to convert it to an array it simply returns `NULL`

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to do anything special for `json_encode()` to output valid JSON.

The "validator" you link to is *not* checking to see if the input is valid JSON; it's checking to see if it matches a particular "schema" (which is not something JSON really has a concept of, and the correctness of the validator is unknown).

It appears to me the issue probably that you're copy-pasting the JSON out of something that's inserting line breaks into it - which makes tools like JSONLint complain.

Comment: I copied the string directly from the database

Comment: Then whatever you're copying it from the database through is adding line breaks, because there are definitely arbitrary line breaks in the dropbox file you linked.